# Assembly instruction confusion, rrux.w and rrum.w

Tags: assembly

I am currently reading some assembly instructions, and I see that two instructions, `rrum.w` and `rrux.w`, keep coming up. I googled these two and did not find anything on it. What do they and how are they are used?

Architecture: [MSP430](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430).

Comment: [This document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf#page247) could be relevant.

Comment: thank you! @jeppe Stig Nielsen

Answer (score 2):

The RRUM instruction can even be found on the Wikipedia entry for the TMS 430.

Using Google I found this document describing both instructions:

http://www.win.tue.nl/~johanl/educ/RTcourse/MSP430%20-%20general.pdf

rrum: Shift right logical register

rrux: Shift right logical memory location

If you are confused by the ".w": This is the instruction size. Some assemblers add ".w" for 32-bit operation and ".h" for 16-bit operation. Other assemblers use ".l" for 32-bit and ".w" for 16-bit so the meaning of ".w" differs from assembler to assembler. ".b" is used for 8-bit operation.

TMS 430 seems to use ".a" or ".b" only in conjunction with the rrum/rrux operations. However some assemblers may "unify" the meaning of the suffixes so ".w" is always used for 16-bit (or 32-bit?) operation instead of ".a".